# How to install perl 5.10 from MinGW installation manager?

Tags: windows, perl, mingw

When I try to build openssl on windows with msys.bat, `./configure mingw shared` reports an error.

> Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.8, stopped at ./configure line 12.

The MinGW Installation Manager lists 5.8.8 as a repository version. 
[image]

How can I get a more recent version of perl? I already installed strawberry perl, but I don't know if it's possible to connect it to msys.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things you could try:

Perl-MinGW project, which seems to be an update of perl for MinGW: https://sourceforge.net/projects/perl-mingw/?source=navbar

Or try to use MSYS2, which already uses a newer version of perl: https://www.msys2.org/